# What are all the dependencies for the Windows service "Internet Connection Sharing (ISC)"?

Tags: windows-7, internet-connection, services, dependencies

I am unable to start the service because it says "Error 1068: The dependency service or group failed to start." Hence I need to know which services I need to enable/start so that I can turn on ICS.

---

I found out all the dependencies:

- Application Layer Gateway Service
- Network Connections
- Network Location Awareness (NLA)
- Plug And Play
- Remote Access Auto Connection Manager
- Remote Access Connection Manager
- Remote Procedure Call (RPC)
- Telephony

Then I had to set those all to "Automatic", and make sure all their respective dependencies are at least set to "Manual" and not Disabled", and restart my computer. After restarting my computer, the "Internet Connection Sharing (ICS)" service was started.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Application Layer Gateway Service
- Network Connections
- Network Location Awareness (NLA)
- Plug And Play
- Remote Access Auto Connection Manager
- Remote Access Connection Manager
- Remote Procedure Call (RPC)
- Telephony

Answer (score 3):

They should be listed on the "Dependencies" tab in the properties of the service:

[image: ICS Dependents]

Even though it's for XP, perhaps check out this MS Article: ["Error 1068" Error Message When You Try to Turn On Internet Connection Sharing](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/827328).

Also perhaps ensure any 3rd party anti-malware/firewall are disabled/uninstalled and see if that helps any.

Comment: I verified that those four services are started, yet it still gives the same error that the dependencies failed to start. Anyway from my experience I know that not all dependencies are actually listed there.

Comment: Edited it to add a bit more info.  Good luck. :)

Comment: I found the info on my own, thank you anyway. Voted up for effort.